# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Failed re-generating the iPhone native folder

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I've recently upgraded from Worklight 6.0 to 6.1 and I'm trying to get an update from a 6.1 Worklight Server from an iPhone that has a version built from 6.0 on it. This does not seem to work, so I figured I must manually deploy a version on the iPhone that was built from 6.1 in order to get the update. So I deleted the native folder under iPhone so that when I build it would regenerate itself, but I got the following error on build:

```
iphone build failed: com.worklight.builder.sourcemanager.handlers.ios.settings.IOSAddRemoveSettingsRefHandler - cannot update content of pbxproj file
```

My Worklight Studio version: 6.1.0.00-20131219-1900
The platform version in my application-description is also 6.1.0.00-20131219-1900.
I was able to rebuild the Android version and redeploy on my phone and successfully get updates.

Any ideas what the problem could be? I thought that if I deleted the native folder I should be able to always generate a new one by building.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Locate your temp folder ([Windows](http://appscout.pcmag.com/microsoft-windows/272405-find-the-temp-folder-in-vista-and-windows-7), [OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/how-do-i-find-out-the-system-temporary-directory), [Linux](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/tmp.html))
3. Delete the `wlBuildResources` folder
4. Open Eclipse
5. Re-build

Comment: It worked! I only added the step of also deleting the iphone/native folder while Eclipse was closed. Thank you.