# Worklight - FWLST1040E: android build failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using worklight 6.1 for my mobile app project. My problem is why I got this error when I try to build my android app.

```
[2014-02-18 15:36:12] FWLST1040E: android build failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/var/folders/1k/k94ws4g107bgncjlp0_0vlwr0000gn/T/wlBuildResources/6.1.0.00.20131126-0630/environments/base/android/obscurerArgs.txt' does not exist
```

Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try deleting the wlBuildResources folder.
See my answer here: [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Failed re-generating the iPhone native folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008162/ibm-worklight-6-1-failed-re-generating-the-iphone-native-folder/)

1. Close Eclipse
2. Locate your temp folder ([Windows](http://appscout.pcmag.com/microsoft-windows/272405-find-the-temp-folder-in-vista-and-windows-7), [OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/how-do-i-find-out-the-system-temporary-directory))
3. Delete the `wlBuildResources` folder
4. Open Eclipse
5. Re-build