# Eclipse Null Pointer when adding HTML under skin folder

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-skins

I have a simple hybrid App for Android phones. I have a skin folder created for Android tablets. I create an HTML file under the android.tablet but if this HTML file name match the same name of the HTML file under common folder then Eclipse shows a pop up error message that says:
'Building Workspace' has encountered a problem
Errors occurred during the build. 
Java.Lang.NullPointerException

I have Eclipse Kepler SR1 64bits on OS X I get same error in Eclipse Juno on Win7.

This is the exception:

Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.worklight.studio.plugin.utils.PluginUtils.toCoreException(PluginUtils.java:138)
    at com.worklight.studio.plugin.builders.PreviewResourceDeltaVisitor.visit(PreviewResourceDeltaVisitor.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:49)
    at com.worklight.studio.plugin.builders.WorklightProjectBuilder.incrementalBuild(WorklightProjectBuilder.java:73)
    at com.worklight.studio.plugin.builders.WorklightProjectBuilder.build(WorklightProjectBuilder.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.worklight.studio.plugin.builders.PreviewResourceDeltaVisitor.visit(PreviewResourceDeltaVisitor.java:78)
    ... 19 more

Comment: And your Worklight version is?

Comment: Which edition of eclipse? In addition to the version, you also need to ensure you're using a supported edition: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. See here for direct links to the supported versions and editions that work with Worklight: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/download/

Comment: Worklight Version is 6.1

Comment: Eclipse is IDE for Java EE Developers

Answer (score 0):

I *cannot* confirm this using Worklight 6.1.0:

1. Created new project and application, "test"
2. Added the Android environment
3. Add a skin to the Android environment, "android.skin"
4. Copied common\index.html to android.skin\

   No pop-up
5. Changed the HTML a bit
6. Run As > Run on Worklight Server

   No pop-up

Suggestions:

- Try with a new workspace
- Close Eclipse and [follow these instructions to delete the wlBuildResources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847067/worklight-fwlst1040e-android-build-failed-java-io-filenotfoundexception) folder

Comment: I belive there must be something with the project or HTML itself.  As soon as I copy common\index.html to android.tablet\  the auto build will kick off and give the error.   This is what I see in the Eclipse Log:                                                                        Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".                                                 org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.worklight.studio.plugin.utils.PluginUtils.toCoreException(PluginUtils.java:138)
 at com.worklight.studio.pl

Comment: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.worklight.studio.plugin.utils.PluginUtils.toCoreException(PluginUtils.java:138)
 at com.worklight.studio.plugin.builders.PreviewResourceDeltaVisitor.visit(PreviewResourceDeltaVisitor.java:112)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:69)

Comment: You could of course just add the exception to your question, you know.

Comment: I have deleted the the wlBuildResources folder but same problem after I touch or update the HTML under android.tablet/      I have added the exception to the question....

Comment: You can also try re-installing the plug-in in a new copy of Eclipse and a fresh workspace.

Comment: I have reinstalled Eclipse + Studio plug ins on OSX and still get the same error. I am not sure what could be wrong or unique with this particular project that makes Eclipse throw a Null Pointer...