# Building IBM worklight: why the error: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I created a sample app in worklight studio. The app is running fine in simulator. But at times, when I rebuild the application or start the server from Run as->Run on Worklight Development Server, I am getting the following build error:

```
[2014-10-24 09:58:58] Starting build process: application 'MySearch', all environments 
[2014-10-24 09:58:58] FWLST1040E: common build failed: Parameter 'directory' is not a  directory
[2014-10-24 09:58:59] FWLST1040E: android build failed: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
[2014-10-24 09:58:59] FWLST1040E: iphone build failed: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
[2014-10-24 09:58:59] Application 'MySearch' with all environments build finished with errors.
```

The error goes only after several eclipse restart/cleaning the project/removing the app from worklight development server.
Any clue about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Go to your TMP folder and delete the wlBuildResources directory
2. Use a new instance of Eclipse
3. Use a new workspace

See if the error repeats itself.

Comment: can you please give the locaation of wlBuildResources folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847067/worklight-fwlst1040e-android-build-failed-java-io-filenotfoundexception

Comment: Thanks Idan for the quick reply