# Worklight build error Failed initializing ClientProjectBuilder

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have suddenly started getting worklight build errors like below. I have no clue why it started happening suddenly. The code was working fine until the remote machine I use for Xcode builds was rebooted. Any clue what could be causing it ?

ipad build failed: Failed initializing ClientProjectBuilder
android build failed: Failed initializing ClientProjectBuilder
iphone build failed: Failed initializing ClientProjectBuilder

Regards
Avi

Comment: Avi, please mark my answer as resolved.

Answer (score 16):

The solution to this error, typically, is to delete the `wlBuildResources` folder, located in the TMPDIR of the OS.

See here: [Worklight - FWLST1040E: android build failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847067/worklight-fwlst1040e-android-build-failed-java-io-filenotfoundexception)

1. Close Eclipse
2. Locate your temp folder ([Windows](http://appscout.pcmag.com/microsoft-windows/272405-find-the-temp-folder-in-vista-and-windows-7), [OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/how-do-i-find-out-the-system-temporary-directory))
3. Delete the `wlBuildResources` folder
4. Open Eclipse
5. Re-build

It may be helpful to also delete the native folder before closing Eclipse, however do note that if you have written custom native code you should first back it up so it won't be lost(!).

Comment: Idan, I tried deleting the native folder and rebuild but that did not help.
However the exact steps you mentioned above fixed it ! 
Thank you !

Comment: @Idan, Do you have any suggestions for what to do if this occurs while using the WL CLI? I have tried deleting the wlBuildResources and wlPreview folders as well as deleting the server files and rerunning wl create-server but none of this has helped.

Comment: mmmm, try removing the .ibm folder; backup your stuff.