# MobileFirst 7.0 - unable to modify wlBuildResources parent directory during automatic build operations

Tags: ios, ant, build, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm performing concurrent build operations in an OSX Build Unit where the MobileFirst 7.0 and iOS/Android native artifacts are the outcome. Occasianally, builing the native ipa file for iOS fails because some of the content that should be added to the iOS `native` folder from underneath the folder `wlBuildResources` is inexplicably missing:

```
[xcodebuild-archive] CpResource CordovaLib/VERSION ...........
[xcodebuild-archive]     cd .................
[xcodebuild-archive]     builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -strip-debug-symbols -strip-tool ..........
[xcodebuild-archive] error: /../../../CordovaLib/VERSION: No such file or directory
[xcodebuild-archive] 
[xcodebuild-archive] ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[xcodebuild-archive] 
[xcodebuild-archive] 
[xcodebuild-archive] The following build commands failed:
[xcodebuild-archive]    CpResource CordovaLib/VERSION ..........
[xcodebuild-archive] (1 failure)
```

The missing file here is `wlBuildResources\7.0.0.00.20160808-1524\environments\base\ios\native\CordovaLib\VERSION`. This file should be added by the Ant task app-builder to the iOS `native` folder.

While investigating this issue, I intended to work around it by setting a different parent folder for wlBuildResources at each build, to be sure that all the resources were recreated each time.

Several other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582419/worklight-build-error-failed-initializing-clientprojectbuilder) indicated that when the folder wlBuildResources is created/recreated it is appended to $TMPDIR in OSX. Hence I customized the value of $TMPDIR in the same shell that executes the app-builder ant task. But, even this way, the task recreated the folder wlBuildResources under the same parent directory as before.

So I have the following questions:

1) Are the Ant tasks provided by MobileFirst for building the product artifacts suitable to work in concurrency/parallel?

2) Is it possible to indicate to the app-builder ant task where to append the wlBuildResources folder? I suspect that the task uses `getconf DARWIN_USER_TEMP_DIR` as parent folder for wlBuildResources.

Thanks, Simone.

Comment: Only question 1) is duplicated, question 2) has been answered just here

Comment: @idan I have removed the word "deploying" that made question 1) a duplicate, now the question is about "building" and it's not a duplicate.