# Worklight project upgrade error

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, upgrade

I encountered a problem with Worklight project that is new technology for me.

Error while upgrading Worklight project from version 6.1.0.00-20131126-0630 to 6.1.0.01-20140821-0406 (also tried 6.1.0.02-21041216-0421). Error message:

```
Unexpected error during upgrade: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFolderToZip(Zipper.java:190) 
at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFolderToZip(Zipper.java:202) at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFolderToZip(Zipper.java:202) 
at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFolder(Zipper.java:106) at com.worklight.upgrader.internal.Zipper.addFolder(Zipper.java:91) 
at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.backupCurrentProject(WLUpgradeEngine.java:645) at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.performUpgrade(WLUpgradeEngine.java:294) 
at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.upgradeProject(WLUpgradeEngine.java:188) at com.worklight.studio.plugin.upgrader.WLUpgraderWorkspaceJob.runInWorkspace(WLUpgraderWorkspaceJob.java:127) 
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38) at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Kepler Service Release 2 Build id: 20140224-0627 
Win8.1 x64

Any help or suggestions are very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All the builds you have tried are very, very old.
As an IBM customer you should download the latest available iFix for your Studio installation from [IBM Fix Central](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/). The latest should be from July 2015.

Please try again with that version.

You can also attempt to delete the wlBuildResources folder per the instructions in this question: [Worklight - FWLST1040E: android build failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847067/worklight-fwlst1040e-android-build-failed-java-io-filenotfoundexception)

Finally, if this is still happening also with the latest available iFix (see above), provide a project that this issue is reproducible with so that it could be debugged.

Comment: Thanks Idan. I tried both upgrading to the latest as well as the folder removing option. None helped. I can't send out the sources as this is a client project. Plus, I am the only one in the team having this problem (other team members are running Mac/Linux). I will try a different OS