# IBM Worklight - does not re-generate iphone .zip in iphone enviroment's package folder

Tags: ios, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using eclipse 4.3 with Worklight 6.2 in Debian 7.6. After deleting iphone.zip from iphone enviroment's package folder and rebuilding the enviroment again, worklight does not regenerate it. i tried to fix by following the solution of a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008162/ibm-worklight-6-1-failed-re-generating-the-iphone-native-folder) but the solution's steps didn't work for me. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting Worklight 6.2, the package folder that used to exist under the iphone folder has been removed.

If you'd like to create a zip of your generated Xcode project (= the iphone\native folder after you select Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server), find the native folder in your file system and zip it yourself.

You can find the native folder's location by right-clicking on it in Eclipse and select Properties.