# Worklight cannot update content of pbxproj

Tags: iphone, ibm-mobilefirst, pbxproj

I create my project and have everything build on the pc in Eclipse. I then open the iPhone environment's xcodeproj file on the Mac in XCode and build the app I created. I have to swith Enable BitCode to No in order for it to build, but after that it builds and deploys without issue.

The problem is if I do that several times while updating the app, I eventually hit an error in Worklight that says:

> FWLST1040E: iphone build failed: Source handling process - cannot
>   update content of pbxproj file Application 'XXXXXXXXXXX' with
>   environment 'iphone' build finished with errors.

At this point I can not do anything to stop this error from happening. I'll back out my last change, but it still errors. The only way I can solve this is to delete the entire project and start from scratch. I then make all my changes BEFORE my initial build, so I am starting where I left off, and it builds fine.

Any ideas what is causing this error, or how what I can do besides deleting everything and starting from scratch several times a day?

Worklight 6.2
Eclipse Luna 4.4.2
Xcode 7.0.1

Comment: Does this solution to this issue help you at all?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008162/ibm-worklight-6-1-failed-re-generating-the-iphone-native-folder

Comment: It now builds, but it won't generate an xcodeproj folder now so I can't open it in Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that deleting the native folder inside the iPhone folder in Eclipse and then building using Studio will make it work again.

Comment: Ran a clean, then rebuilt the entire project, then built for iPhone Environment and it worked. Still not sure what the cause is...